# android edit text trims lengthy text on device but not in emulator

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

The text itself is set using the following line:

```
mtxtComment=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textComment);
mtxtComment.setText(Html.fromHtml(strTextComment), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

mtxtComment is an editable TextView (EditText). Layout is quite usual:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textComment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10px"
        android:paddingRight="6px"
         android:scrollbars="vertical"
         android:editable = "false"
         android:textColor = "@android:color/white">
```

Text length is about 77kb, of which about 1/3 is actually displayed on screen. 
Emulator shows it all.
Texts shorter then 20kb are shown ok on the device.

First screenshot - on device, this is the very bottom of the text:
[image: First screenshot - on device, this is the very bottom of the text]

second screenshot - emulator - this is not the bottom, it is possible to scroll to the bottom:
[image: second screenshot - emulator - this is not the bottom, it is possible to scroll further to the bottom]

Any ideas on what's going on and how it can be fixed?
Or if you don't know exact answer but can point me into the right direction, please reply too.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution:

I added the following atribute to the layout XML:

**android:maxLength="300000"**

Probably by default it is set to 9000 for some reason, because my lengthy text got cut at that size.
In the following fragment of the code **txtComm** object had mText property of full length, but WordtoSpan had mText limited by 9000:

```
        Spannable txtComm=(Spannable) Html.fromHtml(strTextComment);

        mtxtComment.setText(txtComm, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        Spannable WordtoSpan = (Spannable) mtxtComment.getText();
```